# How to teleport players from one radius to the same relative locations in another?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to teleport all the players within a region [say a 5x5 region around entity A], to the same relative positions around another entity [entity B].

E.G. in command form something like this:

```
tp @p[dx=5,dy=2,dz=5] @e[dx=5,dy=2,dz=5]
```

Currently using this which is what I've been trying:

```
execute as @e[name="Destination"] at @e[name="Location"] run teleport @p[dx=5,dy=2,dz=5] @s[dx=5,dy=2,dz=5]
```

Currently using 1.13.2

Comment: Try execute as @e[name=Destination] at @s run teleport @e[name=Location,dx=5,dy=2,dz=5] @s. I don't use dx, dy and dz too much so I'm just assuming they do what they're supposed to already. You could also use distance=..5 but that would also go up and down five blocks.

Comment: No luck unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use relative teleporting. Say for example you have two areas, and these two areas are 100 blocks apart. You could do the following:

`tp @p ~100 ~0 ~0`

If the player is in the upper left corner of area 1, they will teleport to the upper left corner of area 2. The number you place in the command would correspond to how far apart the centers of each area are.

Comment: Yeah I know I can use relative teleportation, however the destination will vary (hence why it's an entity), therefore I can't just use static values :/

Comment: Tilde coordinates are relative to the command block, not the entity being teleported.